# How can we get Network tab information (Header, Response, etc) using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I have an application to automate where I am facing issues when trying to perform some action(uploading images) using scripts. But when I try to do the same action manually it works. So how can I know which API request is causing a problem.

PS: I tried giving thread sleep time while running the scripts and try to open network tab, but it wasn't work :(

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get `Header` and `Response` information you can use [BrowserMob Proxy](https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy). But I doubt it will give you the information to fix your upload issue. If you are trying to upload an image through `Selenium` please remember you need to send the local location of the image to the "upload locator" on the page directly using `sendKeys` method instead of clicking on the upload button and using the system dialog box which is not possible.

Comment: I am uploading the image using sendkeys only. Actual issue is how I can get Header & Response info. Image upload was just an example.

Anyways thanks for replying will try to use BrowserMob Proxy :)